# How to find out which procedures and functions are using a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm deleting a table (table a), and I want to know which of the functions, procedures and views are using my table (table a).

Comment: By querying `[dba | all | user ]_dependencies`  data dictionary view `where referenced_name = your_table_name`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select * from dba_source where text like '%:tablename%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check in **`DBA_DEPENDENCIES`** table using below query:

```
  select * from DBA_DEPENDENCIES where REFERENCED_NAME ='tableA' --YOUR TABLE NAME;
```

**QUICK CHECK**:

```
    create table TEST (id number(5), name varchar2(50) ); 
     --Table created

    insert into TEST values(1,'mahi');
     --1 row created. 

    commit;                                                                                                               
     --Commit complete.   

    create or replace procedure PROC_TEST As
    v_name varchar2(50);
    BEGIN
    select name into v_name from TEST where id=1;
    dbms_output.put_line('o/p : ' || ' ' || v_name);
    END;
    /
       --Procedure created. 

      Exec PROC_TEST();                                                                                                                       
      --o/p :  mahi                                                                                                                 

      --PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**QUERY:**

```
 select * from DBA_DEPENDENCIES where REFERENCED_NAME = 'TEST';
```

[image: QUERY OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

i thing bellow query by "davegreen100" will work but need to place upper at both side so that it will work for upper as well as lower case.

```
select * from dba_source where upper(text) like upper('%:tablename%')
```